# Signal Analysis/Processing Textbook

Tags: reference-request, signal-processing

Can anybody recommend me a decent Signal Analysis/Processing textbook. If possible one that deals a little with MATLAB. I have an little knowledge of Real Analysis and fourier transforms. Wavelets i have only had a brief introduction to.

Thanks

Comment: There's a [dsp.SE](http://dsp.stackexchange.com/) site; you might be able to get better answers there.

Comment: You might want to take a look at [this question](http://dsp.stackexchange.com/q/427/77) on [dsp.se], especially Marvin's answer. Please do not re-ask it there; it will definitely be closed.

Comment: I have *Signals and Systems* by Oppenheim et al. that's recommended in an answer to that question, and I like it.

Comment: Tamal Bose's [Digital Signal and Image Processing](http://www.amazon.com/Digital-Signal-Image-Processing-Tamal/dp/0471327271/ref=la_B001KDV7U8_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1339026266&sr=1-1) interests me for its part of introduction on the stability of multidimensional signal, yet this book does not include wavelet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry about asking the question here. I was unaware of the existence of dsp.stackexchange.com. Thanks for the links.